# Writing a web viewer for iOS that uses iTunes File Sharing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Does anyone have an example of this?  I've managed to set up a `UIWebView` that loads a single page through iTunes File Sharing.
Problem is since File Sharing won't allow directories I need a way of unzipping a zip file that would contain all the images/javascript/css etc with the page.

I've tried a few of the zip compression frameworks with little avail for iOS, maybe something a little better is out there?